# How to determine whether a method argument is a literal/scalar string in PHPStan, even if concatenated

Tags: phpstan

I want to determine whether a given method argument is a string. I thought I had a pretty good solution (below), but it turns out not to handle some important edge cases--namely concatenated strings, which I want to be treated the same as one string value.
Variables, constants, `sprintf()`, other function calls, or *anything* but scalar strings are forbidden, even when concatenated with a string. How can I achieve that?

```
<?php

final class StringArgumentOnlyRule implements Rule
{
    public function getNodeType(): string
    {
        return MethodCall::class;
    }

    public function processNode(Node $node, Scope $scope): array
    {
        // Get the first argument.
        $allArgs = $node->getArgs();
        $firstArg = reset($allArgs);

        // The argument is a string. The rule correctly passes.
        if ($firstArg->value->getType() === 'Scalar_String') {
            return [];
        }

        // Concatenated strings return a type of
        // Expr_BinaryOp_Concat. The rule wrongly fails.

        return ['Must be a string.'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. One solution is to type your method parameters as `literal-string`: https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types#other-advanced-string-types
2. Another option is to get the type of the argument and ask if it's a literal string:

```php
$firstArgType = $scope->getType($firstArg->value);
$isLiteralString = $firstArgType->isLiteralString();
```