# How to determine if a node is inside certain class constructor in PHPStan

Tags: phpstan

I want to determine whether a `MethodCall` node is inside a certain class constructor. More specifically, I want to know if a method is being called within an exception constructor.

This is the background: A third-party translation service uses static analysis to find translatable strings in my code. It does so by analyzing call to a `::translate()` method. It only supports string literals, so I can't pass variables or method calls, for example--*except when re-throwing exceptions*, where there's no way to know the strings ahead of time. Here's an example:

```
<?php

class ExampleClass
{
    // I know this string ahead of time.
    const BAD = 'BAD';

    function exampleMethod()
    {
        // Should PASS: I control the string, so I pass it directly.
        $this->translate('Good');

        try {
            $this->throwsAnException();
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            // Should PASS: I don't "own" the string--but it still has to
            // be passed through the translation system for "reasons"--so
            // the only option is to pass the method call.
            throw new Exception($this->translate($e->getMessage()));
        }

        // Should FAIL: I control the string, so I should pass the literal.
        $bad = 'BAD';
        $this->translate($bad);

        // Should FAIL: Same thing. It's my string, so I should pass the literal.
        $this->translate(self::BAD);
    }
}
```

I have a (basically) working solution to prohibiting non-string values here: [How to determine whether a method argument is a literal/scalar string in PHPStan, even if concatenated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77233294/how-to-determine-whether-a-method-argument-is-a-literal-scalar-string-in-phpstan). What I still need is to ignore the rule when the node is in a `new Exception()` call. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is a nicely asked question, it really is, but it’d be much better to ask it in PHPStan’s GitHub Discussions 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your rule is registered to process the `MethodCall` node which is the `translate` method call.

You essentially want to "look around" the method call to see if it's inside `new Exception`.

Currently you need a custom node visitor to set the attribute on the node. Here are the details: https://phpstan.org/blog/preprocessing-ast-for-custom-rules

And please ask in GitHub Discussions next time, you'll get a good answer too and quickly :) https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/discussions

Comment: Oh! I assumed it would be considered more courteous to ask the question here, first. Thanks, @Ondřej Mirtes. I'll ask it on GitHub next time. 